# Wordpress submenu not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

For some reason my Wordpress submenus/dropdowns are not working correctly. They are not hiding under their parents and are always displayed.

I used the base theme from http://www.underscores.me which from what I understand should have dropdowns working out of the box. I customized it to my liking but I didn't really do much with changing the menus. But apparently I did do something.

**Registering the Menu**

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'tct-redi' ),
) );
```

**Added a couple more items to the menu**

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
     return $items .= '<li class="social-link"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ColumbiaREDI" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li class="social-link"><a href="https://twitter.com/columbiaredi" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
                    <form name="search-form" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="/">
                        <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                            <button type="submit" form="searchform" formmethod="get" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

**Placing the menu in my header.php**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 'depth' => '2' ) ); ?>
```

Does anything look off here that could be causing this? Here are screenshots of the menu layout in the admin dashboard and what it looks like on the frontend.

**Menu Layout**

[image: Menu layout]

**Submenu always open**

[image: Submenu not working]

Comment: The theme is probably using some css class to hide the submenu. Check on the original theme if there is any class on the dropdown and change your HTML in your `wp_nav_menu_items` filter depending of what you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized it was because I am using bootstrap in my site.

Simply adding the wp-bootstrap-navwalker to my functions.php and following the instructions on the GitHub page solved all of my issues!

-[GitHub Package](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)